# Screen flickering and touchpad not recognizing in dell laptop

Tags: dell, touchpad

(Ubuntu newbie here),

I have recently tried installing Ubuntu (18.04.6 LTS) on my Dell laptop of following configuration

```
  Dell Inspiron-3521- Intel® Core™ i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4 .
  Graphics - Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
```

Problem : On booting , the screen start flickering with ubuntu logo and after that Touch pad is not working. I tried installing ubuntu 20.04 LTS as well, but same issue.
What confuses me is that, everything works fine when i enter boot options and select ubuntu from the list.
How can i fix this ? .
(Please feel free to ask for any further clarification)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the difference between a Live Session and a bare-metal installation is the drivers that are used. To ensure your system has all of the basic drivers installed, consider running this in Terminal:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

After doing this, be sure to reboot.

Another item to check would be "hardware enablement". As you're using an LTS (Long-Term Support) version of Ubuntu, you can make use of this feature by running this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

With this, you may notice that your machine runs a little bit better.

Comment: The driver autoinstall command shows 'No drivers found for installation' as output.